# How to determine what version of python3 tkinter is installed on my linux machine?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hi have been scavenging the web for answers on how to do this but there was no direct answer. Does anyone know how I can find the version number of tkinter?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In Python 3, it's `tkinter` with a small `t`, and you need to import it. Thus:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.TkVersion
8.6
```

If you didn't import it, you'd get the error you mentioned.

Comment: When I import it I get the error saying 'ImportError: No module named '_tkiner'', I have done sudo apt-get install python3-tk and sudo apt-get install tk-dev. They both say there are in the newest version but my error still shows up when I try import tkinter.

Answer (score 24):

`tkinter.TclVersion` and `tkinter.TkVersion` described in other answers provide the major and minor Tcl/Tk versions but not the patch number.

On the other hand, the [`info patchlevel`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.html#M36) Tcl command returns the version in the `major.minor.patch` format.

```
import tkinter

tcl = tkinter.Tcl()
print(tcl.call("info", "patchlevel"))

# Output:
# 8.6.10
```

The following should be preferred to call the command from a Tkinter app, which already has an associated Tcl interpreter:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
...
print(root.tk.call("info", "patchlevel"))

# Output:
# 8.6.10
```

Answer (score 7):

Type this command **on the Terminal** and run it.

> **python -m tkinter**

A small window will appear with the heading *tk* and two buttons: *Click Me!* and *QUIT*. There will be a *text* that goes like ***This is Tcl/Tk version ___***. The version number will be displayed in the place of the underscores.

Answer (score 4):

You cal so invoke `TclVersion`:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.TclVersion
8.6
```

Tested for Python 3.6.5 and Python 3.5.2 (Ubuntu 16.04.4):

Answer (score 3):

Run Tkinter.TclVersion or Tkinter.TkVersion and if both are not working, try Tkinter.__version__

Comment: They all give back an error saying NameError: name 'Tkinter' is not defined. I even tried with a smaller case "t" and getting the same error.

Comment: This looks like Python 2 code. Also, my copy of `tkinter` doesn't have a `__version__` attribute, which is why I'm here.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal try as follows:

```
python -m tkinter or python3 -m tkinter
```

Comment: *cute!* "This is Tcl/Tk version 8.6 This should be a cedilla: ç"