# How can I check the EXACT python tcl-tk/tkinter version, i.e. x.y.z and not x.y?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I know that I can check python tkinter version in two ways in python 3:

```
>>>import Tkinter
>>>tkinter.TkVersion
```

or

```
python3 -m tkinter
```

However they both provide only major version of Tkinter i.e. x.y or 8.6 for example.
So my question is if there is a way to get the exact version of tkinter i.e x.y.z or 8.6.10, 8.5.9 etc. for example?

Comment: Does `tkinter.__version__` give anything different?

Comment: Can this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62761906/4237254

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, should I now delete my question as a previously answered one or leave as it asks more explicitly for this exact information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeless, added the answer for those stumbling on this page

```
import tkinter
tcl = tkinter.Tcl()
print(tcl.call("info", "patchlevel"))
```